# why org.w3c.dom.DocumentBuilder sneakily adds attributes to XML elements on its own

Tags: java, xml, dtd

After a few days of confusion and trying different libraries to validate an XML document with an XSD (that I'm 100% positive is valid according to the XSD), I finally discovered that the reason for the failure that `org.w3c.dom.DocumentBuilder` and `org.w3c.dom.Document` decided to sneak a bunch of attributes into the DOM. Here is one of many validation errors I am receiving:

> Value '127' of attribute 'high_value_range' of element 'API_Version' is not valid with respect to the corresponding attribute use. Attribute 'high_value_range' has a fixed value of '4294967295'.

As you can see in this sample `test.xml` file, I am *not* specifying the attribute `'high_value_range'`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE My_Doc SYSTEM "MyDoc.dtd">
<My_Doc xmlns="http://my.namespace.org">
  <Package>
    <API_Version>1</API_Version>
  </Package>
</My_Doc>
```

Here is the code to parse the XML file and print the DOM:

```
package client;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import org.w3c.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class Writer
{
    //method to convert Document to String
    public static String getStringFromDocument(Document doc)
    {
        try
        {
           DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
           StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
           StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
           TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
           javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
           transformer.transform(domSource, result);
           return writer.toString();
        }
        catch(TransformerException ex)
        {
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc;
        doc = dBuilder.parse(new File("data/test.xml"));
        System.out.println(getStringFromDocument(doc));

    }
}
```

And finally, the result of printing out the parsed `Document` and cause of the subsequent validation failures:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<My_Doc xmlns="http://my.namespace.org" element_tag="GROUP" element_type="GROUP">
  <Package>
    <API_Version element_type="FIELD" field_type="INTEGER" value_upper_range="127">1</API_Version>
  </Package>
</My_Doc>
```

And here is the `MyDoc.dtd` to reproduce:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<?My_Application DTD_Version='6.5'?>
<!ELEMENT My_Doc (Package)>
<!ATTLIST My_Doc  element_tag  CDATA  #FIXED 'GROUP'
               element_type CDATA  #FIXED 'GROUP'
               xmlns        CDATA  #FIXED 'http://my.namespace.org' >

<!ELEMENT Package (API_Version)>

<!ELEMENT API_Version (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST API_Version  element_type      CDATA  #FIXED 'FIELD'
                                    field_type        CDATA  #FIXED 'INTEGER'
                                    high_value_range CDATA  #FIXED '127' >
<?DTD_End Dummy_Processing_Instruction='END'?>
```

Why is `DocumentBuilder` adding all that extra stuff and how do I stop it from doing that?

Comment: This sounds pretty unlikely. Please provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem ourselves. (Out of interest, if you remove the DTD, does that change anything?)

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not able to share the data, DTD, or XSD. At best I can share all of the code if you think that would help, but I provided everything except the junk like `Class`, `try/catch`, `main`, `import`, etc. And yes if I remove the reference to the DTD in the XML file then `DocumentBuilder` does not add all that stuff.

Comment: And I agree it sounds pretty unlikely, I'm as baffled as you are, must be a good question to stump you ;)

Comment: You don't have to provide the *real* data - just enough for us to reproduce it. You should be able to pare down the real DTD and data to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem, and then change the names/values until there's nothing of any importance in there in terms of private information.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay you're right, I added everything to reproduce it.

Comment: Righto. Will have a look - not my area of expertise, but others are much more likely to be able to help you now :)

Comment: If you don't want the attribute `high_value_range` to appear, and if when it does appear it is required by the XSD schema to have a value of 4294967295, then why is your DTD specifying a fixed value of 127?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen I've been wondering the same thing. I don't know much about DTD and XSD so I wasn't sure why that would ever happen. The DTD, XSD, and data was provided to me, rather than authored by me.

Answer (score 3):

When you parse a document with DTD validation enabled, default attribute values defined in the DTD are inserted into the parsed document. If you don't want that to happen, then either don't define a DTD, or suppress DTD validation, or suppress expansion of DTD-defined attribute defaults. (I can tell you how to do that if the TransformerFactory you are using is Saxon, but not for Xalan).

Comment: I added `dbFactory.setValidating(false);` before parsing the document but even with validation disabled it's still adding the extra elements. Unfortunately, I am required to define the DTD so removing that isn't an option.

Comment: Okay I discovered that if I do both `dbFactory.setValidating(false)` *and* `dbFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false)` then it won't add the extra attributes. But the problem is then the subsequent `Validator.validate` call won't attempt to validate the XML doc with the XSD.

Comment: When you say "When you parse a document with DTD validation enabled, default attribute values defined in the DTD are inserted into the parsed document." are you referring specifically to `Javax.xml` library or more generally? Because I create a similar application in C++ with Xerces and it validated properly without expanding the DTD defined attributes.

Comment: The XML specification states (§3.3.2) "When an XML processor encounters an element without a specification for an attribute for which it has read a default value declaration, it must report the attribute with the declared default value to the application". (But it's not required to report it in exactly the same way as an attribute that was actually present in the instance.)